# How to add OpenCV library in spring web application

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, opencv, native

I have developed a desktop application. It has to upload an image, processing it, and give some out put.(braille image to text). That portion - the desktop application - is working fine. However, now I want to develop it as a web Application. I am currently designing that level.

using SpringMVC and maven.

In here I have added OpenCV as a user library,

but when it run give bellow
error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:      no opencv_java248 in java.library.path
```

Help would be appreciated; how to fix this Error?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

is this what you're looking for ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nu.pattern</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.9-4</version>
</dependency>
```

Cause your question seems a bit odd.

Comment: i am lokking for how to fix my error "HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:      no opencv_java248 in java.library.path"..Thanks

Comment: I tried your link ,what is JAVA_OPTS and where put those changes-Djava.library.path="C:\opencv\build\java\x64;C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin"  Thanks

Comment: and check this one : http://answers.opencv.org/question/8288/opencv-244-in-javalibrarypath-error/

Comment: Thanks for your commenting..i solved adding opencv248.dll file to Windows/Sun/java/bin

Comment: Thanks for your commenting..i solved adding opencv248.dll file to Windows/Sun/java/bin

Answer (score 1):

i solved adding  opencv_java248.dll file to Windows/Sun/java/bin

Answer (score 0):

added the  opencv_java248.dll file to Windows/Sun/java/bin

it is in C:\opencv\build\java\x64  (in my case windows64 bit)